# Представление десятичного числа в hex высокоуровневыми средствами

Tags: c++, вывод, форматирование

С помощью каких средств языка C++ можно привести обычное десятеричное число в hex вид?

Именно привести и использовать дальше, без вывода на экран. Для этого можно использовать `sprintf`, но я надеюсь есть более удобный высокоуровнеый аналог.

Comment: А, по-вашему, в каком виде числа хранятся в компьютере?...

Comment: мне нужно получить строку чаров, которая является представлением десятеричной системы в hex...

Comment: Это другое дело :)

Comment: @DenverToha У вас изначальное число - то же строка чаров (от 0 до 9) ? Ведь "десятичное" это именно так. В переменных лежат не десятичные числа

Comment: изначальное число - int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вам хочется особо высокоуровнево...

```
string Hex(int i)
{
    ostringstream os;
    os << hex << i;
    return os.str();
}
```

Но эффективнее -

```
string Hex(unsigned int n)
{
    char s[9] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        s[7-i] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[n%16];
        n /= 16;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Да и `sprintf` тоже неплохо :)